# Can a diatonic melody in one key sound like it is in another key?

Tags: melody, modulation

Here is a simple melody I composed in C# minor but while listening to it closely, the part notated in red seems to me like the music has actually moved across to G# minor. Is it weird to say this since ofcourse all the notes are part of C# minor and I have not used any accidentals but there is just something about the way it sounds at this point. Can music suggest a different tonal center somehow depending on which notes we emphasize from the scale? Obviously ^1 ^3 and ^5 make ^1 sound like the tonic but what happens if you all of a sudden start emphasing other notes, is it possible to make neighboring keys start to sound like the tonic?

In this case, it is ^b7 that starts to get emphasized due to phrasing and it lifts the mood somehow and changes the feeling before finally ending with a sad ^3 ^2 ^1 melodic descent.

[image]

Comment: The trivial example of the answer being "Yes" is me repeating any one note and claiming the piece/excerpt is supposed to be in the subdominant of the repeated note (i.e. the repeated note is not ^1 like you would expect, but ^5). (Yes, this is based on examples I've heard where the piece's melody either starts or ends on ^5.)

Comment: With that being said, I hummed your melody just now and only felt that your red portion lingered on the v chord as a kind of "dominant prep", not changed keys entirely. I've heard both more convincing "modulations" without key signature changes and/or accidentals and more convincing reharmonizations into different keys that use the exact same melody as the original.

Comment: There is a thing called *tonicization*, which is normally done with chromatic chords, not diatonic melodies. Are you asking if a diatonic melody alone can tonicize another tonal center or are you asking if tonicization is even a thing?

Comment: There's an apparent assumption in the title that the "key" of any passage is defined by the last previous key signature. Or at least that it's restricted to one major key and one relative minor.

Comment: There are books and books describing the changes in key (modulations) that occur in various classical works prescribed for music examinations, all so that students can memorise them to recall for an extra mark or two. The internal key changes, which are not usually marked by key signature changes, are normal and desirable, though they will depend the arrangement as well as the melody

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

I think one of the primary things to look at regarding that potential ambiguity is the handling (especially the absence) of a leading tone in whatever area seems ambiguous.

Before reading your score, the example that came to mind is the two major tetrachords of a major scale: `C: ^4 ^3 ^2 ^1` and `C: ^1 ^7 ^6 ^5`. When the key is established with the right handling the scale degrees will be clear. But, if somehow we isolated the two tetrachords, you could have the ambiguity of `C: ^4 ^3 ^2 ^1` and perhaps `C: ^1 ^7 ^6 ^5` sounding like `G: ^4 ^3 ^2 ^1`. With letters, I mean `C B A G` could sound like either `C: ^1 ^7 ^6 ^5` or `G: ^4 ^3 ^2 ^1`, depending on the handling of the rest of the music, especially the leading tone. You can exploit that ambiguity. A typical use is in modulation. Or, if you don't intend the ambiguity, the music could sound different that what you want.

In your score what I think is the more obvious ambiguity is here...

[image]

That isn't necessarily bad, but it's something to be aware of.

If you wanted to make it obviously `C#` minor, you could include the leading tone somewhere, maybe like this...

[image]

The section you marked `G#m ??` is essentially the tetrachord issue from above, because the passage doesn't have a leading tone.

You could add a leading tone to clarify a new key, like this...

[image]

Of course, you don't need to change anything. I'm just pointing out a way to make leading tones emphatically define keys.

If the melody isn't going to be harmonized, and you want to avoid ambiguity of keys, it becomes more critical to get functional the scale degrees of leading tone and subdominant into the music.

Or just let the music be ambiguous, if you want. That's OK too.

> ...the part notated in red seems to me like the music has actually moved across to G# minor. Is it weird to say this since of course all the notes are part of C# minor...

No, not weird. But I think it's tricky to explain, because *not doing something* is what makes the potential key change.

Let's start with the premise that that section clearly implies a `G#` minor triad.

The tone `G#` is the dominant of `C#` minor.

In the key of `C#` minor, when you play a dominant chord the seventh scale degree must be raised. In this case the `B` natural of the key signature needs to become `B#`. You did not do that for this supposed dominant chord. And by doing so you pretty strongly imply a modulation.

Why? Because if you're in `C#` minor and you play a `B`, it's supposed to be a `B#`, especially when it's somehow related to the dominant scale degree `G#`. There are exceptional cases like a step-wise line descending from the tonic, or implying a non-dominant chord, but we aren't dealing with those in your melody, so we consider other factors.

In that passage, you play a `G#`, you play a `B` natural, and not only do you play a `C#` you move to it from the `B` natural. By the conventions of tonic/dominant harmony in the major/minor system, if you wanted to be clearly in `C#` minor, that is not the way to do it. By not raising the seventh scale degree you're at least suggesting the music may not be in `C#` minor anymore. Of course, `G#` minor isn't emphatically the key either, but that is a different matter. The passage has no leading tone for `C#` minor and no leading tone for `G# minor. As it stands there is some ambiguity.

It's not weird for you to hear the passage as potentially in `G#` minor.

Comment: Please excuse the newbie question, but this notation is new to me: "C: ^4 ^3 ^2 ^1".  I couldn't figure out how to google it.  What does this mean?

Comment: @WayneConrad, `^` character is a circumflex, in music it indicates a scale degree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex#Music It should be above the number, but there isn't a character set/font for it, so prefixing the number `^1` is a way to do it. `^1` means scale degree 1, the tonic.

Comment: https://learnmusictheory.net/pdfs/pdffiles/01-02-06-scaledegreenames.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If you mean, can you use the notes of a key to create a melody that sounds like being in another key, then yes of course. It's not what notes you use, it's what you do with them.

Here's a melody in A minor:

[image: melody in A minor]

And here's a melody in D minor:

[image: melody in A minor]

All notes in both melodies are diatonic to A minor.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's why we need to change chords in a piece! Given a key, we couldn't keep playing the same chord all the way through, there would most likely be chord changes throughout.

Taking any of those changed chords for the number of bars they last, that part will sound like it could be in the key of the prevalent chord - even if the notes were diatonic or not.

It's partly what jazz players do when they 'play the changes'.

That said, your example shows only one note difference between the two 'keys', so iy would be easy to slide from one 'key' to another.